# JQuery Click() not working after element ID change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change element id and then do something with it.
This script changes id, but click does not work. Some friends provided the following solution, but I would like to understand why.

Thanks for help.

```
$('#some').hover(
   function(){
       $(this).attr('id', 'new');
   }
);
$('#new').click(
   function(){
       $(this).fadeTo('slow' , 0.2);
   }
);
```

Solution:

```
$('#new').on('click',
function(){
   $(this).fadeTo('slow' , 0.2);
}
);
```

But why can't I use 'click' directly?

Update:

Thank you all for the answer. Here's a follow up:
I used the 'on' method to initiate the click event. Can I then include the same id in the function itself for it to fade?

Code:

```
       $('#new').live('click',
        function(){
       $('#new').fadeTo('slow' , 0.2);
       }
       );
```

I tried on my end but it failed to start the event. Any workaround suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you would be having same controls with same id ie new.id is identical

Comment: I have to say that your code works fine for me in the firebug

Comment: In your code examples, `.click()` and `.on('click')` are absolutely equivalent. Would you mind setting up a demo (like a jsFiddle) to show what the difference is? In the current state of your question it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: To the update: use `this` instead. If you do not know what I am talking about, it would be more beneficial to you to complete the [jQuery event tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/events/) first. We cannot really help you if you are not familiar with the basics, this is not a tutoring site. (also, do not use `live()`, it is deprecated)

Comment: "this" would have worked fine except I have 3 layers for the decision tree: after I click on the button it would update the ID to a new one, and I would need to replicate the process again...looks a bit cumbersome this way so I'll try to come up with another approach

Answer (score 4):

You are changing the DOM property dynamically. And events are attached to DOM, not to DOM property like class,id,name-value, etc. To make it work,[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is the solution:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('click','#new',function(){
   $(this).fadeTo('slow' , 0.2);
});
```

Comment: The question is why does the code marked as "Solution" in the question work. The OP is clearly not giving enough details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#some').hover( 
    function(){ $(this).attr('id', 'new'); 
    $('#new').click( function(){ 
          $(this).fadeTo('slow' , 0.2); 
    })  
});
```

Your problem is when you define the second function, there is no element called $('#new') and the function cannot be binded, so if you define the second function inside the first, you avoid this.

I tried this code, and works perfect for me

1st)Change the id of #some to #new when mouse is over #some element

2nd)Fade #new when clicked #new element